# ¿Cómo crear función que devuelva los últimos 4 dígitos de los números de una lista en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, math

Me piden en un ejercicio que tengo que devolver los últimos 4 dígitos de números que están almacenados en una lista.

Intenté así, pero me devuelve un error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

```
def last_four(x):
    for i in x:
        return i[:4]


ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]
print(last_four(ids))
```

Si pueden ayudarme, gracias.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución que retorna una lista de cadenas con los cuatro últimos dígitos de cada elemento de la lista:

```
def last_four(x):
    return [str(i)[-4:] for i in x]
```

Si quieres obtener los 4 últimos dígitos de `x`, se usa `str(x)` para convertir el valor numérico a una cadena, a la cual se le puede aplicar rebanado de listas.

Como nos interesan los cuatro últimos caracteres, usamos el indice `[-4:]`. La forma que usabas, `[:4]` significa "desde el primero hasta el cuarto", o sea, los cuatro primeros dígitos.

Todo lo anterior enmarcado en compresión de listas, de manera de genera una nueva lista con los cuatro últimos dígitos.

Ahora, si quieres una lista de enteros en lugar de una lista de cadenas, puedes usar esta otra versión:

```
def last_four_int(x):
    return [int(str(i)[-4:]) for i in x]
```

**Demo**

```
ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]
print(last_four(ids))
print(last_four_int(ids))
```

produce:

```
['3005', '2342', '9000', '0002', '2345', '9329']
[3005, 2342, 9000, 2, 2345, 9329]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Candid Moe!

Answer (score 1):

La solución es convertir los elementos de tu lista en String, y así poder cortarlos, ya luego se devuelve a su estado de entero

```
ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]

result = list(map(str, ids)) #Convierte la lista con elementos enteros en elementos string
print(result)

listaActualizada = [ elem[-4:] for elem in result ] #Recorre los elementos de la lista, y les quita los ultimos 4 digitos
print(listaActualizada)

listaActualizadaInt = list(map(int, listaActualizada)) #Devuelve los elementos de la lista a su estado de entero
print(listaActualizadaInt)
```

Estas serían sus respectivas salidas:

```
['17573005', '17572342', '17579000', '17570002', '17572345', '17579329']

['3005', '2342', '9000', '0002', '2345', '9329']

[3005, 2342, 9000, 2, 2345, 9329]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Javier!

Answer (score 0):

deberías especificar como quieres que sea lo devuelto, cadena, entero , lista, tupla.
te muestro otra forma, ya que la lista original son enteros no es necesario convertirla, simplemente obtenés el resultado del módulo

```
def last_four(lista):
   return [x %10000  for x in lista ] # en caso de querer una lista 


ids = [17573005, 17572342, 17579000, 17570002, 17572345, 17579329]
print(last_four(ids))
```

simplemente por que reclaman si tiene números negativos(que no es el caso) es igual de simple:

```
def last_four(lista):
    return [x % 10000  if x > 0  else  x % - 10000 for x in lista] # en caso de querer una lista
```

Comment: Revisa tu respuesta: no funciona con números negativos.

Comment: nunca aclaró que la lista fuese a tener números negativos, la que puso no los tiene, por lo tanto para este caso así como está es correcta.

Comment: @tincopsan. Tienes que ir un paso por delante del usuario. Si hoy te pide una lista de positivos, mañana te pedira una con negativos.

Comment: @Candid Moe que concepto gracioso, el usuario debería no esperar todo hecho, sino según tu comentario debería explicarle todos los métodos de la listas,nodos y árboles binarios que es lo que sigue en listas.

Comment: No, no hay que entregarle todo hecho. Tampoco hay que entregar códigos que fallen.

Comment: volvemos a lo mismo, en lo que está en la pregunta explicitamente, mostrame donde falla el código,antes de que sigas pataleando como un crio